# Java - eclipse - get the .exe file

Tags: java, deployment, installation, executable

[As I understood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233727/how-to-create-an-executable-a-file-that-starts-the-program-on-double-click-like), I need to make a jar file in order to get the .exe.

My problem: I have the method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
```

in EX1 class. When I make: `Export --> Java --> Runnable Jar file`, the class EX1 is not one of my options. What can be the reason?

Thanks

Comment: You need to have run it at least once to create a launch profile first.

Comment: *"As I understood, I need to make a jar file in order to get the .exe.:"*  No, you could always start with .Net based source.  In fact, if all I wanted was an exe, I'd be looking to .Net.  The best way to make a distributable *Java* app. is to Jar the classes and launch them with [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info), which will work on Windows, OS X & *nix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java doesn't have exe files; you'll have a runnable jar; a xxx.jar file. You can execute it as follows:

```
java -jar xxx.jar
```

also, to be able to export the runnable jar, you might have to make a run configuration first...it's somewhere in the menu or icon shortcuts of eclipse

Comment: Sorry, But I stiil don't understand. I do the next steps: press Run--> Run configuration --> press run. It's really run the program, but where is the .jat file?

Answer (score 0):

just to put things clear: An Jar file ist not an exe!

To your problem: 
Eclipse will only provide you the class in the drop down list if you had run these main class at least once directly from eclipse.

These means: Run As / Java Application

After that the class should appear in the drop down list.