# Java Software on USB Key

Tags: java, usb

I wrote a Java software. Now I want to copy it on a USB key and make it able to run in a stand-alone way on computers that probably don't have JVM. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure there is. Don't listen to the spoil sports. [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) lets you bundle your executable jar, any dependency jars, and even a JRE into an executable file.

There is, unfortunately, no way to make one cross-platform solution, because JRE implementations themselves are not cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a Java to EXE program, like [Exelsior JET](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/jet.html).

Answer (score 1):

i think best way will be if you will try to fit jvm on that usb stick.

Answer (score 0):

For each computer/architecture you want to run your java code on you need a JVM.

You could provide several JVM's next to your java code for different architectures.

Or you can create an executable for a specific platform (such as MS Windows)  see
[How do I create an .exe for a Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516399/how-do-i-create-an-exe-for-a-java-program)

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a collection of [Portable Application Creators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_application_creators). If that's an overkill, just use a private JRE.

If you need to save space on your USB key, have a look at this [7-Zip SFX trick](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/blog/excelsior-jet/java-app-as-a-single-exe/) (works for both private JRE and Excelsior JET.)