# How To Create Setup exe File (Mysql Database Administrator Project) in java

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

Recently I Create a java project using Mysql Database administrator & eclipse. Now I want to try to make this project as a exe(Setup) file. I try exe4j, Jar2exe to make exe file. But i am not success. There is a problem: Mysql Database is server based Database. Now how can i create exe file with mysq database server. 
Anyone can answer me?

Comment: Some installers allow to chain child installers, however, if you don't need the server functionality of MySQL, I'd recommend taking a look at some of the embedded/single user databases, like H2

Comment: You can follow this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516399/how-do-i-create-an-exe-for-a-java-program

and this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011664/compiling-a-java-program-into-an-exe