# Creating .exe from Java for people to use

Tags: java, user-interface, exe

So i found a possibility for me to put my java programm into an .exe
But i am unsure wether or not it would be possible for others without an IDE to just click on it and run the Programm as intended
Its just a simple randomizer with GUI
and i want it to be used by people how do not code or anything
maybe you guys have a good input where to start or even an somewhat easy solution

Im Thankful for every constructive Input
Kind Regards, A

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create an .exe for a Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516399/how-do-i-create-an-exe-for-a-java-program)

Comment: You will have to create a .jar, not an .exe. One you have the jar created you can share your program with others if they have installed the Java Virtual Machine. Search in your IDE if you have an export to jar option.

Comment: At first, thanks for the fast reply guys.
i will look more into it.
My goal would be to have a programm so that my friends who want to use the programm would NOT have to need to download anything other than my programm 
i found that in most people just want to click on an exe. or sumthing similar and the programm does the rest

Comment: Then, maybe the Java languaje it's not the best choice for your app. It is on feature of the language to create apps that run on the JVM so the are independent of the underlying hardware and operating system. I'm sure there are some workarounds for this, but it is not the intended use of the language.

Comment: What kind of language would you recommend?