# Exporting Netbeans project

Tags: netbeans

This is my first NetBeans Project. It's a simple data management application with a small MySQL database.

What I want is to be able to export this project as an exe.

I've tried using advanced installer but it didn't work or I didn't quite know how to handle it properly.

My project directory currently contains the following lib folder / libraries folder / src folder /target folder with the JAR executable file.

I've seen multiple NetBeans users get a folder called dist with the executable JAR file there. MaybeI have a problem with my version of NetBeans (NetBeans 15).

Comment: You should explain exactly which installer you used, what happened and what you are expecting to happen instead (or just where you are stuck).  The file you want I think it normally in the /dist folder, and has the same name as your project.  Make sure to manually do a full build first.

Comment: there is no disp folder by the way when i do a clean and build the path thows the jar file in the target folder what i want is to create an exe file

Comment: You have not shown us the step-by-step process you already tried. You only told us that you tried "using advanced installer" and that it "didn't work". Have you researched all of the discussions and answers in this question: [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/516399/12567365) And there are other similar SO questions you can also research. Maybe those will help. Or, if not, you can [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: Side note: You will see a `/dist` folder when you create a NetBeans "Java with Ant" project (less common these days), and a `/target` folder when you create a "Java with Maven" project (more common these days). But that is more-or-less irrelevant to your question, I think.

Comment: Also, just to clarify - do you want to create an executable JAR file, or a Windows-style `.exe` file? If it's just an executable JAR file, then maybe this is more relevant: [How can I create an executable/runnable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/574594/12567365) You can also research more questions like this. (Do you also expect the database to be embedded in the JAR/application? That adds another twist to your question.)

Comment: @andrewJames this worked thank you very much also one more thing i use a virtual machine linux operating system for my netbeans my operating system is windows 11 and its version of netbean 15 laggs for a while everytime i try to import images or jars just simply every time i use the windows explorer and try to locate files or folders is there any fix to that ? I APPRECIATE THE PREVIOUS ANSWER THANK YOU AGAIN ANDREW

Comment: Glad you got it working - that's the main thing. But here are some more notes on how SO generally works: (a) If an existing answer resolved your problem, you should close this question (marking it as a duplicate of the relevant question where you found the answer). You can upvote that answer, as well (once you have 15 reputation points). (b) You should take the [tour], read [ask] and visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for guidance.

Comment: (c) If you have a new problem, then do some research, and if you cannot find an answer, then ask a new _specific_ question (but please follow the guidance in [ask]).